# Why Windows system having Cassandra Server is hanging?

Tags: windows, cassandra

For testing purpose, I have installed Cassandra Single Node server in my windows 64-bit System where the Cassandra Server running Continuously as a Service. After 2 or 3 Days of Continuous run, my System is getting hanged which does not allows any operations at all. But Cassandra Server is serving requests from Client applications with out creating any problem. What is the reason for this problem and How to solve this issue?

Comment: It is going to be difficult to help you without knowing things like the versions of Cassandra, Java, and Windows; or without seeing any error messages.  Important to note, but Cassandra is only supported on Windows as of version 3.0.  And even then, it is still recommended to be run on Linux.